# What's the easiest way to find out relevant video card/driver information

Tags: xorg, drivers, hardware

I need to know my video card/chipset, X11 Driver, driver version, and Xorg version. It seems to me that finding this information is always scattered throughout various utilities. Is there an easy way to get it all at once?

Answer (score 3):

`lspci -vvv` for video card
`X -version` for Xorg version.

Comment: this still doesn't tell me what X11 driver is being run.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to get it all is in the X logs (typically something like `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`). It's buried in a heap of other information though.

Comment: ugh, I was afraid that was the best answer I'm going get

Answer (score 1):

You should try  `lspci`, which stands for "List PCI devices", it will show you what graphic card you have.

`Xorg -version`, will show you your version of Xorg.

`vim  /etc/X11/xorg.conf` will show you the drivers that Xorg is using.

Hope the clears it up a bit.

Comment: except that it says nothing about things like X.org version, driver version, or really anything but my hardware... I could also do `lshw`, or `xdriinfo`, or even `xdpyinfo` but it all ends up with me still missing some critical info and making other stops.

Comment: Then parametrize the command.